# NSMutableArray can not add object?

Tags: objective-c, ios6

I have 2 model:

```
@interface Program : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * name;

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *guides;
@end

@interface Guide : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *name;
@end
```

And I add some guides to program from one xml:

```
    Program *program = [Program new];
    program.name = @"My list"
    for(DDXMLElement *guideElement in [programElement nodesForXPath:@"guide" error:&error])
    {
        Guide *guide = [Guide new];
        guide.name = [guideElement stringValue];// [p attribute:@"name"];
        [program.guides addObject:guide];
        NSLog(@"load guide number: %d", [program.guides count]);
    }
```

The out is always "load guide number: 0"

Comment: Have you created the NSMutableArray? Such as: self.guides = [NSMutableArray array]

Comment: Because callling any method of nil object will return nil value. In this case, [program.guides count] will return 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

program.guides is nil, since you never created it.

Comment: Thank you very much, it works after I add `NSMutableArray *guides = [NSMutableArray new];
` and `program.guides = guides;
`

Answer (score 1):

In your `Program`'s `init` method, add:

`self.guides = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];`

Or, more sloppily, before your `for` loop add:

`program.guides = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];`